# count occurrences of a string in a structure

Tags: string, matlab, count

I have a structure `mydata` and I need to access one of its fields `mydata.myfield`, and within that field, access another field `mydata.myfield.mysecondfield`. In the last field, `mydata.myfield.mysecondfield` I need to check how many times a particular string (`'apple'`) occurs.

I have tried with:

```
 aaa=unique(mydata.myfield.mysecondfield,'apple')
 bbb=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(mydata.myfield.mysecondfield,x)),aaa,'un',0)
```

but I get this error: `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.`

The structure contains fields with both strings and numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem may be due to the fact that the structure is a little bit different from how you describe it. Following your question, I created it as follows:

```
mydata = struct();
mydata.myfield.mysecondfield = {'apple' 'apple' 'orange' 'banana' 'apple' 'kiwi'};
```

and since I'm not getting the same error you get, I think the underlying types may be slightly mismatching. Anyway, given `mydata` defined as above, if you change your code as follows, it should work but it will return the count of every unique occurrence within the field:

```
aaa = unique(mydata.myfield.mysecondfield);
bbb = cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(mydata.myfield.mysecondfield,x)),aaa,'un',0)

bbb =
      4×1 cell array
      [3]
      [1]
      [1]
      [1]
```

If you only want to count the number of `apple` occurrences, you should use the following approach instead:

```
apple_count = sum(strcmp(mydata.myfield.mysecondfield,'apple')); % 3
```